# instant delete when the button is cliked

Tags: php, html

im trying to delete from a datatable when i click the remove button the data will be removed for a quick action in the admin side but my code dose not work i tried to fix it but i don't see any problem in the code here is my code

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
<table id="datas" class="table table-striped table-bordered fixed" style="width:100%">

    <thead style="color:black;" >
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Company Name</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Price Per Gram</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Product Price</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Total Price</th>

        <th class="text-center">Actions</th>


    </thead>

    <?php
    $get = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM stock;");
    ?>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($get)) {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $company=$row['company_name'];
        $name=$row['product_name'];

        $weight=$row['weight'];
        $price_per_gram=$row['price_per_gram'];
        $quantity=$row['quantity'];

        $type=$row['type'];
        $category=$row['category'];
        $price=$row['product_price'];
        $img=$row['img'];
        $total=$row['total_price'];
        ?>
            <tr>
            <td ><?php echo $id;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $company;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $name;?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $weight;?> g</td>
            <td><?php echo $price_per_gram;?> $</td>
            <td><?php echo $quantity;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $type;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $category;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $price;?></td>
            <td>
                <img  src="product_img/<?php echo $img; ?>" style="height:5rem;width:5rem;border-radius:10px;">
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $total;?></td>
             <td style="width: 20px"> <a href="editstock.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" class="btn btn-gradient-primary">Edit</a>
                 <button class="btn btn-danger" name="delete"  type="submit" value="<?php echo "$id" ?>">Delete</button> </td>

            </tr>


    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php 


 if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {

$delete = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM stock WHERE id= ".$_POST['delete']." ");
header("location:viewstcok.php");

} ?>
```

i give the delete button a value when clicked so it will delete with that value but it did not seems to work can any one help me

Comment: show be placed inside `<form></form>` tag

Comment: Your button has any direction or onClick action you have to create a form or create onClick function for that button also “$id” not good your button will try to delete a $id not 1-2-3.. etc.

Comment: @ManuVarghese i really did not notice that :(
thanks it solved my problem

Comment: @MhamadCommander accept my answer :)

Comment: @ManuVarghese ok i can accept it after 6 min  thanks again :)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to  placed table inside `<form></form>` tag

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<form>
<table id="datas" class="table table-striped table-bordered fixed" style="width:100%">

    <thead style="color:black;" >
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Company Name</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Price Per Gram</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Product Price</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Total Price</th>

        <th class="text-center">Actions</th>


    </thead>

    <?php
    $get = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM stock;");
    ?>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($get)) {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $company=$row['company_name'];
        $name=$row['product_name'];

        $weight=$row['weight'];
        $price_per_gram=$row['price_per_gram'];
        $quantity=$row['quantity'];

        $type=$row['type'];
        $category=$row['category'];
        $price=$row['product_price'];
        $img=$row['img'];
        $total=$row['total_price'];
        ?>
            <tr>
            <td ><?php echo $id;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $company;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $name;?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $weight;?> g</td>
            <td><?php echo $price_per_gram;?> $</td>
            <td><?php echo $quantity;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $type;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $category;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $price;?></td>
            <td>
                <img  src="product_img/<?php echo $img; ?>" style="height:5rem;width:5rem;border-radius:10px;">
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $total;?></td>
             <td style="width: 20px"> <a href="editstock.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" class="btn btn-gradient-primary">Edit</a>
                 <button class="btn btn-danger" name="delete"  type="submit" value="<?php echo "$id" ?>">Delete</button> </td>

            </tr>


    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
<?php 


 if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {

$delete = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM stock WHERE id= ".$_POST['delete']." ");
header("location:viewstcok.php");

} ?>
```